# How to use polars cut method returning result to original df

Tags: python, python-polars

How can I use it in select context, such as df.with_columns?

To be more specific, if I have a polars dataframe with a lot of columns and one of them is called x, how can I do pl.cut on x and append the grouping result into the original dataframe?

Below is what I tried but it does not work:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "b": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "x": [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]}
df.with_columns(pl.cut(pl.col("x"), bins=[2, 4, 6]))
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: It seems that for now `pl.cut()` creates separate dataframe that is not related with main df.

Comment: you should edit out your second question and ask it as a separate question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.cut.html#polars.cut), as of 2023-01-25, `cut` takes a Series and returns a DataFrame.  Unlike many/most methods and functions, it doesn't take an expression so you can't use it in a `select` or `with_column(s)`.  To get your desired result you'd have to join it to your original df.

Additionally, it appears that `cut` doesn't necessarily maintain the same dtypes as the parent series.  (This is most certainly a bug) As such you have to cast it back to, in this case, int.

You'd have:

```
df=df.join(
    pl.cut(df.get_column('x'),bins=[2,4,6]).with_column(pl.col('x').cast(pl.Int64())),
    on='x'
)

shape: (5, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ x   ┆ break_point ┆ category    │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ f64         ┆ cat         │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 2.0         ┆ (-inf, 2.0] │
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ 4.0         ┆ (2.0, 4.0]  │
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6.0         ┆ (4.0, 6.0]  │
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 7   ┆ inf         ┆ (6.0, inf]  │
│ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 9   ┆ inf         ┆ (6.0, inf]  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: It appears that [`pl.cut()` does not always maintain original order](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4286) which is another issue.

Comment: @jqurious if we're just joining it back to the original, why does the order matter, perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you mean though.

Comment: No - it's my mistake - it isn't relevant if you're joining as you say, apologies.

Answer (score 2):

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     "b": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
     "x": [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]}
)

df.with_columns(
    pl.col('x').cut([2, 4, 6]).alias('x_cut')
)
```

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ x   ┆ x_cut     │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ cat       │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ (-inf, 2] │
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ (2, 4]    │
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ (4, 6]    │
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 7   ┆ (6, inf]  │
│ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 9   ┆ (6, inf]  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───────────┘
```

---

### Old solution

As of `0.16.8`, the top-level function `pl.cut` has been deprecated. You have to use the [series method](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.cut.html#polars-series-cut) `.cut` instead now, which returns a three-column DataFrame.

```
# get x column as a Series and then apply .cut method
df['x'].cut(bins=[2, 4, 6])
```

It returns a DataFrame like the following:

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ x   ┆ break_point ┆ category    │
│ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ f64 ┆ f64         ┆ cat         │
╞═════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 2.0         ┆ (-inf, 2.0] │
│ 3.0 ┆ 4.0         ┆ (2.0, 4.0]  │
│ 5.0 ┆ 6.0         ┆ (4.0, 6.0]  │
│ 7.0 ┆ inf         ┆ (6.0, inf]  │
│ 9.0 ┆ inf         ┆ (6.0, inf]  │
└─────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

If you just want to add the cut categories in your main DataFrame. You can do so in a `with_columns()` directly:

```py
df.with_columns(
    df['x'].cut(bins=[2, 4, 6], maintain_order=True)['category'].alias('x_cut')
)

# or
df.with_columns(
    x_cut=df['x'].cut(bins=[2, 4, 6], maintain_order=True)['category']
)
```

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ x   ┆ x_cut       │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---         │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ cat         │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ (-inf, 2.0] │
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ (2.0, 4.0]  │
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ (4.0, 6.0]  │
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 7   ┆ (6.0, inf]  │
│ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 9   ┆ (6.0, inf]  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: As a side question, how can I do ```over``` if using ```cut``` the way you specified?

Comment: @lebesgue I'm not sure if you can combine them at this moment since `.over` is an expr, which has been used in a context like `with_columns`. For now, `.cut` is a series method, so...

Answer (score 1):

As of `0.18.5` you can use cut as an expression. (Due to the lack of reputation I  unfortunately can't post this as a comment to previous replies)

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"numbers": range(0, 20, 2)})
(
    df.with_columns(
        pl.col("numbers").cut([4, 7, 15]).alias("bins")
    )
)
```